# Angular check all checkboxes no matter their state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Again, something so simple, Angular complicates.

I have some checkboxes:

```
<!-- $scope.checked == true -->
<li ng-repeat="(type, description) in types">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checked">
</li>
```

I don't care if they're checked or not - one could be check the other unchecked. I simply want to trigger a 'check all' from within the corresponding controller.

What baffles me is that some of the approaches online seem to take like 5+ lines of code.. how can that be. 5+ lines for such a simple thing, forget it.

All advice appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Still not working folks, here's my controller code:

```
$scope.checked = true;

$scope.checkAll = function()
{
    $scope.checked = true;
};

$scope.submitForm = function()
{
    $scope.checkAll();

    // other stuff...
};
```

If one checkbox is checked and another unchecked, nothing happens on `submitForm()`

Comment: try $parent.checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that checked is always "true".  You are not really changing the value.

Instead you could count up, as 1,2,3 are all different but all truthy.  Feels a little hacky though.

```
$scope.checked = 1;

$scope.checkAll = function()
{
    $scope.checked++;
};
```

Comment: Boom that did it, I would be interested in a less hacky approach but thank-you none-the-less. Seems elegant enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add

```
$scope.checkall = function(){
$scope.checked=true
}
$scope.checkall()
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6ge315o/7/)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-checked` can take any expression so long as it resolves to truthy or false. You could have a variable `master` that you can flip in your controller when you want to tick all boxes.

```
<li ng-repeat="(type, description) in types">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="master">
</li>
```